# IPhone persist Model

Tags: iphone, persistence, plist

I would like to persist an object of a class (not just `NSString`´s). For instance, I have this class:

```
** News.h:**

    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
    @interface News : NSObject
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * atrib1;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * atrib2;
    @end

** News.m:**

    #import "News.h"
    @implementation News
    @synthesize atrib1;
    @synthesize atrib2;
    @end
```

Should I have to use a plist to storage it? How should I do it?

Comment: have a look at [`NSCoding`](http://developer.apple.com/library/iOS/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCoding_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: Thanks! That is the standard and the recommended way to serialize an object. Also, an alternative (simpler) could be storing data (if they are simple enough) in a dictionary such as in [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502193/writing-nsdictionary-to-plist-in-my-app-bundle) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using NSCoding:

In News.m, I have added:

```
- (void) encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)encoder {
    [encoder encodeObject:atrib1 forKey:@"key1"];
    [encoder encodeObject:atrib2 forKey:@"key2"];
}

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    self = [super init];
    atrib1 = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"key1"] retain];
    atrib2 = [[decoder decodeObjectForKey:@"key2"] retain];
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc{
    [super dealloc];
    [atrib1 release];
    [atrib2 release];
}
```

In News.h:

```
@interface News : NSObject<NSCoding>{
    NSCoder *coder;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * atrib1;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * atrib2;

@end
```

To read update and persist a new object in the plist:

```
- (IBAction)addANewNews:(id)sender {
//Plist File
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *plistPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myplist.plist"];

//Reading current news
NSData *oldNews = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
NSMutableArray *news = (NSMutableArray *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:oldNews];

if (news == nil) 
    news = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//Adding a new news
[news addObject:aNewNews];
NSError *error;
NSData* newData = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:news];
//persisting the updated news
BOOL success =[newData writeToFile:plistPath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];

if (!success) {
    NSLog(@"Could not write file.");
}else{
    NSLog(@"Success");
}
}
```