# Writing to Cordova.plist file in Phonegap causes error

Tags: objective-c, cordova, plist, nsdictionary

I have added the following to my Cordova.plist file:

```
Key: EnableEverything
Type: Boolean
Value: YES
```

I then use the following code to read and write the plist file:

```
NSString *adKey = @"EnableEverything";

NSString *pathToSettingsInBundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Cordova" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableDictionary *plist = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile: pathToSettingsInBundle];

NSString *enableEverything = [[plist valueForKey:adKey] stringValue];
NSLog(@"EnableEverything: %@", enableEverything); // this returns 1, which is correct.

// Disable in plist.
[plist setValue:NO forKey:adKey];
[plist writeToFile:pathToSettingsInBundle atomically:YES];

NSLog(@"EnableEverything: %@", enableEverything); // never reaches this line
```

I get the following error:

```
2012-09-07 14:20:12.168 slq[958:707] *** WebKit discarded an uncaught exception in the webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: delegate: <NSInternalInconsistencyException> -[__NSCFDictionary removeObjectForKey:]: mutating method sent to immutable object
```

There seems to be a problem when it's trying to write to the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing a file in the app bundle. This is prohibited by apple. check this: [writing NSDictionary to plist in my app bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502193/writing-nsdictionary-to-plist-in-my-app-bundle?rq=1)

You have to copy the plist to a folder you are allowed to change, for example the documents folder.