# How to save an array to .plist in the App's mainBundle in swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, plist

How I can save array to .plist with array type?

I try this, but is not working

```
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Setting", ofType: "plist")
    let arrayWithProperties = NSArray(array: [
        NSNumber(integer: nowThemeSelected),
        NSNumber(integer: imageForBackgroundNumber),
        NSNumber(integer: imageForButtonNumber),
        NSNumber(integer: colorOfButton)])


    arrayWithProperties.writeToFile(path!, atomically: true)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100262/save-data-to-plist-file-in-swift

Comment: possible duplicate of [writing NSDictionary to plist in my app bundle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502193/writing-nsdictionary-to-plist-in-my-app-bundle)

Comment: do you have an answer without using NSArray?

Answer (score 5):

You can't write to the main bundle in iOS, everything inside your Apps bundle is read only.

> [The App's bundle ] directory contains the app and all of
>   its resources. You cannot write to this directory. To prevent
>   tampering, the bundle directory is signed at installation time.
>   Writing to this directory changes the signature and prevents your app
>   from launching. You can, however, gain read-only access to any
>   resources stored in the apps bundle.

Consider reading the [file system programming guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemProgrammingGuide.pdf) and then persist your plist to the correct location. Preferably the Documents directory or the Library directory. Up to you.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant thank you very much sir! Was quite an aggressive down vote there

Comment: The answer was originally one sentence and didn't answer the posted question "How I can save array to .plist with array type?".

Comment: @IanMacDonald my apologies sir, updated since to reflect more

Comment: that programming guide sucks big time, the original question tag is swift not objc.

Comment: @GAlexander unfortunately Objective-C isn't going away anytime soon but I don't see how it makes a difference what language the guide was written in? That guide is pretty rock solid though don't see where the hate comes from?

Comment: @Galasko from someone with a background in most languages EXCEPT objc, i find objc archaic, convoluted and obfuscated.  in perl file I/O can be done in one or two lines of code.  i find mixing old legacy NSDictionary, Dictionary, NSmutableDictionary, etc a real pain in the a$$.  and apple pi$$es me off by not having any decent examples in swift.  i have a simple 2d array i just want to write to a plist file, this should be simple but it isn't

Answer (score 1):

You can't write to the Bundle directory but you can write to the Documents directory. So, use this code!

```
let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
var path:NSString = documentsPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Setting.plist");
```

When you'll writeToFile() use this:

```
arrayWithProperties.writeToFile(path as String, atomically: true)
```

Good Luck!