# Swift3 not writing to the file

Tags: swift, swift3

In the below code I am trying to write to a file that I have in my project in xcode. But for some issue its not writing to it. I am getting no updated text in my file.(JSON file)

```
        responseString = "Some Text"           
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mapsdatademo", ofType: "json") {
            do{
                try responseString.write(toFile: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
            }catch {"Error writting data"}
        }
```

I am able to read the file with:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "mapsdatademo", ofType: "json") {
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)}
```

Note: I am trying get get json data and write that into a file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to save an array to .plist in the App's mainBundle in swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26889507/how-to-save-an-array-to-plist-in-the-apps-mainbundle-in-swift)

Answer (score 1):

iOS is sandboxed.  You can read from the bundle but not write to it.  Write to the documents directory.

```
if var path = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    path = path.appendingPathComponent("mapsdatademo.json")
    do{
        try responseString.write(toFile: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }catch {"Error writting data"}
}
```

Answer (score -2):

your problem is responseString.write(toFile:)

```
responseString = "Some Text"
 do {
         try self. responseString.write(to: path!, atomically: true, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
 }catch{
            print(error)
 }
```

Comment: No, this is not the reason for the problem.